# Bash Variable Contains '\r' - Carriage Return Causing Problems in my Script

Tags: python, bash, variables, carriage-return

I have a bash script (`rsync.sh`) that works fine and has this line in it:

`python /path/to/rsync_script.py $EMAIL "$RSYNC $PATH1 $PATH1_BACKUP"`

I want to break the command (it's actually much longer than shown here because my variables have longer names) in two and use something like this:

```
python /path/to/rsync_script.py \
$EMAIL "$RSYNC $PATH1 $PATH1_BACKUP"
```

But when I do this I get the error:

`scripts/rsync.sh: line 32: $'admin@mydomain.com\r': command not found`

It puts the carriage return, `\r` in there.

How can I break this line up and not include the carriage return?

Comment: Did you edit this script on  Windows machine?

Comment: Well, no, I'm on a Windows 7 machine but I am ssh-ed (using putty) into a Linux machine and I made the script using vim.

Comment: Run dos2unix on your script to strip the \r

Comment: Hrm, that `\r` still feels out of place. If you don't have `dos2unix` or `dtox` already installed, re-edit the file with `vim`, and run `:set ff=unix` immediately before `:wq`.

Comment: It looks like it is in Windows line endings.  The visible line ends in ```\```.  It's expecting ```\{\n}``` but instead it's getting ```\{\r}{\n}```.

Comment: Thanks for these comments - I will try them out!

Comment: also, can your double check that the previous line doesn't have space or other junk trailing the ` \ ` .  We all seem to focus on the ` \r ` but not notice that bash complains that its a command that it cannot find.

Comment: yes, trailing spaces (or tabs) after the `\` can bolix things up! Good luck.

Comment: Yah, before I posted I double-checked the trailing spaces.  In fact, I typed the entire line over again to prevent this - no extra spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out...  I made a mistake in this question and I got so much awesome help but it was me doing a dumb thing that caused the problem.  As I mentioned above, I may have copied and pasted from Windows at some point (I had forgotten since I did most of the edits in vim).  I went back and wrote a short script with the essentials of the original in vim and then added in the '\' for line break and the script worked just fine.  I feel bad accepting my own answer since it was so stupid.  I made sure to up-vote everyone who helped me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like Windows line endings.

Here's how you can check in Python.

```
repr(open('rsync.sh', 'rb').read())
# If you see any \\r\\n, it's windows
```

Here's how you can fix it:

```
text = open('rsync.sh', 'r').read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
open('rsync.sh', 'wb').write(text)
```

### Edit

Here's some code that shows the problem.

```
# Python:
open('abc-n.sh', 'wb').write('echo abc \\' + '\n' + 'def')
open('abc-r-n.sh', 'wb').write('echo abc \\' + '\r\n' + 'def')
```

And then run the files we made...

```
$ sh abc-n.sh 
abc def
$ sh abc-r-n.sh 
abc 
abc-r-n.sh: 2: def: not found
```

Comment: I think the source code has incorrect line endings.  I'm providing a way to correctly format the line endings.  The code above is meant to be run one time on the existing file.  I'll change the file names in the example to 'rsync.sh'.

Comment: I added an example that makes a 'good' file and one that makes a 'bad' file.  The 'bad' gives a similar error as the question.  My original code converts the 'bad' to 'good'.

Comment: I apologize for the many edits.  I believe everything is correct now.

Comment: I think I may have, at some point, copied and/or pasted to and from the script in vim, from Windows.  This could have very well added incorrect line endings.  I will try an experiment with creating the bash script in vim with a new name, typing all of it in Linux to see if that's the case.  Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you can chnage the python script, maybe it will be easier to pass it the variable names thenselves, instead of their content.

From within the Python code you w=have better and more consistent tools to deal with whitespace characters (like \r) than from within bash.

To do that, just change your .sh line to

`python /path/to/rsync_script.py EMAIL "RSYNC PATH1 PATH1_BACKUP"`

And on your rsync_script.py, use os.environ to read the contents of the shell variables (and clear the \r's in them) - something like:

```
import os, sys
paths = []
for var_name in sys.argv(2).split(" "):
     paths.append(os.environ[var_name].strip())
```

Comment: The programs run fine unless I break the line in the shell script.  Using the line you mention, `python /path/to/rsync_script.py $EMAIL "$RSYNC $PATH1 $PATH1_BACKUP"` is already what I had (see original post)...  This is the way I make it work now.

Comment: Sorry -  I typed it incorrectly here - I meant passing the variable names, without the `$`, not their contents. Fixing now.